# RoR 4 form_tag AJAX request issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, spotify

So I am trying to do an AJAX request in my form_tag. Basically, a user can enter a song name or an artist's name and I want to simply post what they searched for into a playlist (very simply here)

These are my files:

**My form**

```
 <%= form_tag({:action => 'capp'}, method:'GET', class: 'ui form', remote: true , id: 'song_form') do %>
      <div class="one field">
        <div class="field" style="width: 100%">
           <%= text_field_tag :query %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <%= submit_tag("Search Song" , class: 'ui large green button') %>
  <% end %>
```

**Where I am trying to put the query entered**

```
<div id="query"></div>
```

**My 'app' Controller which has that action**

```
class AppController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :js

  def create
    passcode = params[:passcode]
    if passcode != nil && passcode.length > 1
        redirect_to :controller => app, :action => capp, :passcode => passcode
    end
  end

  def capp
    @passcode = params[:passcode]
    @query = params[:query] <-- I used pry and the query was being updated but the view itself was not. 
    if @query != nil
      respond_to do |format| 
        format.html
        format.js {}
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**My capp.js.erb file**

```
addSongToPlaylist("<%= @query %>");
// For the record. I tried to also do this:
// addSongToPlaylist("<%= j render @query %>"); <-- But the app errored out saying render was an undefined method name...and all the online tutorials have their function rendering for some reason.
```

**My capp.js file**

```
function addSongToPlaylist(query) {
    var c = "</br>" + query;
    $("#query").append(c);
}
```

All I am hoping for is that the query I entered in the form above be placed in the 
    
location below. But the as soon as I hit submit, the application doesn't do anything. the request goes through (I can see the server sending the GET request) but the view doesnt update. Please help!

*I followed the tutorial on doing AJAX calls and for some reason it's still not working*

Comment: Hi, are there any errors being returned in the console or the browser console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, why aren't you using a [`path helper`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#path-and-url-helpers) for your `form_tag`?

You'd benefit from using the likes of:

```
#config/routes.rb
get "/search/:query", to: "application#search", as: :search
```

This will allow you to use the following:

```
<%= form_tag search_path, remote: true, method: :get %>
    <%= text_field_tag :query %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search" %>
<% end %>
```

This will send a [`get` request](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp) to your `/search/:query` path, which you'll then be able to process with your JS (explained in a second):

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  respond_to :html, :js
  def search
    @passcode = params[:passcode]
    @query = params[:query]
  end
end
```

This *should* handle the request for you, looking to open `app/views/application/search.js.erb`

--

**JS**

For sake of clarity, let's just put the function into your called JS file:

```
#app/views/application/search.js.erb
$("#query").append("<br> <%=j @query %>");
```

This will do what your `addSongToPlaylist` function is doing.

Considering you've populated the `@query` variable, and are passing the ajax properly, this should work.

---

**Debug**

One of the main problems you'll have is that you're not debugging your application.

In this instance, there are a number of potential issues which could prevent your Ajax from firing:

> 1. Your ajax isn't being passed (IE `JQuery` is not loaded)
> 2. Your path is incorrect
> 3. Your controller isn't handling the request properly
> 4. You're not handling the JS correctly

The way to initially test is to look at the *network* tab of your browser's *developer console*:

[image]

To access it, `right-click`, `inspect element`, then select `network`. This will give you a list of all the requests you've sent to your server, and their responses.

When you click your "form submit" button - check to see whether a new request is invoked. If not, it will generally mean you don't have `jquery` in your app (which is required by the `Rails UJS`).

--

Next, you need to check your Rails console to see if you're getting any requests. If not, it will not show anything coming through.

What you're expecting is to see a new set of commands triggered when you submit your "search" form. This will show you which controller#action has been triggered. If it's right, move forward.

--

Finally, you need to check your JS.

You can do this by using `alerts`:

```
#app/views/application/search.js.erb
alert("<%=j @query %>");
$("#query").append("<br> <%=j @query %>");
```

If the alert fires positively, you've got a hit.

Comment: I tried that and this is the error I got. I'm not quite sure why I am getting the error though because :query is part of the route itself.

    No route matches {:action=>"search", :controller=>"application"} missing required keys: [:query]

Comment: OK this is really weird...I removed the ":query" from the "/search/:query" route and i put an alert like you suggested in my search.js.erb file...and the alert went off..but the div tag was NOT updated. Do you know why that may have happened?

Comment: Alright, last update- I fixed it but I still dont know fully why it works:

1) I removed the ":query" and I renamed my <div id="query" /> tag to somethign else. What was happening is that the query form was automatically assigned the id "query" so there were two elements with the same ID. 

Thanks for your help! Learned quite a lot. :)

Comment: No problem! BTW for the routes, if you want to use a conditional parameter, you put it in brackets: `get "search(/:query)`